# Trying to bind an output to my tableviewCell UI Element in RxSwift

Tags: swift, uitableview, textfield, rx-swift, rxdatasources

I have an output that lives in my VM and based on some change I want my textfield that resides in my custom tableviewCell to change in some way. I am unsure about how to have my UItextfield that lives in the tableviewcell bind to my output.

Comment: Help us help you. Show us your code. How are you making your table view cell? What is the type of the output in the view model?

Answer (score 0):

```
  let index = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
  if let cell  = tbl.cellForRow(at: index) as? TableViewCell {
        print(cell.textF.text)
        // Do whatever you want

  }
```

Comment: Can you please explain your situation?

Comment: I have a tableviewCell that contains a textfield property that I need access to but my tableview is in another view controller, while I have access to that tableview I don't have access to anything that is inside the tableviewcell. Hope this helps

Comment: While this may answer the question, code only answers are generally regarded as lo-quality. Providing some more description and context on why will improve the quality of this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure when you want to get the data, but if you want to do this when the user touches the cell, just implement the following method of `UITableViewDelegate`:

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if let cell  = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? YourTableViewCellClass {
        let cellLabelText = cell.yourTextField.text
        // Do whatever you want with cellLabel

        }
    }
```